# Why is there an (x^2)/2 in the normal density function?

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, intuition

If the speed of a car is $v = at$, at time $t$ it will be $\frac{1}{2}at^2$ units away from the origin.

If an ideal spring is displaced $x$ units away from its original position, it gains $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ units of potential energy.

The area of an circle is $\frac{1}{2}\tau r^2$, where $\tau = 2\pi$

It is clear that all of these $\frac{1}{2}vt^2$ patterns come from integrating a linear function, where the squared term is the variable being integrated, and another being a kind of speed (derivative), or ratio ($\pi$ is a ratio).

And if we look at the normal density with mean at zero and precision $p$:

\begin{equation*}
  \sqrt{\frac{p}{\tau}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}px^2}
\end{equation*}

It seems that this is statement of saying the probabiltiy of $x$ decreases exponentially as the quantity $\frac{1}{2}px^2$ increases. Let's call this quantity $\alpha$.

Now if we assume that $\alpha$ comes from integrating the function $f(x) = px$ with respect to $x$, how can this $\alpha$ and $f$ be interpreted? In the examples of car, spring and circle area, we have every motivation to take integration, but here in the context of probability, what does taking integral of $f(x) = px$ actually mean?

Comment: Are you using p to represent 1/variance then you have given the formula for a N(0, $\sigma^2$) density?  But I fail to see how your argument relates to the normal distribution.

Comment: A key difference here is that in the normal distribution, $px^2/2$ is *unitless*. For example Boltzmann's ideal gas law gives a gaussian distribution for particle velocity, and the exponentiated quantity is $E/kT$ where $E$ is the kinetic energy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution

Comment: @AlexR. But if we take $x$ to be people's mean height, in meters, in the US, for example, then both $x$ and $\sigma$ will have meaningful units

Comment: @HaochiKiang: Of course they have units. I'm saying that $x^2/2\sigma^2$ is unitless.

Answer (score 4):

The question is why we divide by two in the exponent of normal density function. The answer is that we don't need to divide by two to get a normal distribution, but variance of the distribution depends on this factor.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Definition), Gauss himself didn't divide by two.

The normal density function for normal standard distribution (mean=0, variance=1) as we use it is:

$$\varphi(x) = \frac{e^{- \frac{\scriptscriptstyle 1}{\scriptscriptstyle 2} x^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\, $$

Gauss used a simpler definition of normal standard distribution, with mean=0 but with variance=$\frac{1}{2}$:

$$ \varphi(x) = e^{-\pi x^2} $$

Then, the answer to your question is that the =$\frac{1}{2}$ factor doesn't come from an integral. It's just a normalization factor that was introduced to get a more convenient normal standard distribution.

Furthermore, it makes the parameters in the distribution function of an arbitrary normal distribution meaningful, since they are its mean and standard distribution. Without the dividing 2, instead of $\sigma$ the pdf would have a parameter related to standard deviation, but not equal.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\, e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$$

Comment: I think the question is asking something else entirely.

Comment: @AlexR. I must admit that something in the question sounds weird according to my interpretation of it. If it's about another kind of normal distribution or another density I can withdraw my answer.

Comment: To me, your answer seems to justify even more that $\frac{1}{2}$ is necessary or special: it is the $\frac{1}{2}$ that makes $\sigma^2$ equal to $E(X^2)$.

Comment: @HaochiKiang Yes, that's the point  in the last paragraph, but more than special it's useful. This way $E(X^2)$ is a parameter. Otherwise, the parameter would be  $2E(X^2)$ and its interpretation would be less straightforward. I suppose variance was less used in time of Gauss than nowadays - at least, I'm sure they didn't call it variance.

Comment: The normal density function for normal standard distribution (mean=0, variance=0) ?

Comment: @DeepNorth Yes, normal standard distribution as we choose to define it nowadays (mean=0, variance=0), because it's more useful, but there are different possible choices (please see the linked Wikipedia article). If the 1/2 factor bothers the OP, he might prefer Gauss's choice.

Comment: Gauss has proposed $e^{-x^2}/\sqrt{\pi}$, the formula you quote was proposed by Stigler (check Wiki again and the reference they quote).

Comment: @Pere The Standard Normal distribution has variance=1. IE: the mean and variance are the additive and multiplicative identities, respectively.

Comment: @Jelsema Thank you. I failed to notice that typo even when DeepNorth commented on it.